# Error 500 rom Djanjo when trying to send my form data in JavaScript to my Django Url

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, forms, django-forms

I am trying to build a ToDo List in Djanjo and I am having issues while trying to build the edit view functionality, below is my home.html file

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7" style="height: 450px; overflow: scroll;">
                <!-- List of all the tasks for the day -->

                {% for task in tasks %}

                <div class="card m-1">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <span id="task_{{ task.pk }}_text">{{ task.task }}</span>
                        <span style="position: relative; float: right;">
                            <a href="{% url 'mark_as_done' task.pk %}"class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Mark as Done</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'delete_task' task.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                            <!-- When this button is clicked, a textbox/form will appear, after it appears and you press submit task
                                is updated -->
                            <a onclick="showTextBox('{{ task.pk }}')" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                            <form id="textbox_{{ task.pk }}" onsubmit="saveValue(event, '{{ task.pk }}')" method="post">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="text" id="inputValue_{{ task.pk }}" name="edited_task" placeholder="Update task">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                            </form>
                        
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                {% endfor %}

            </div>``
```

Next is my script, where I try to send the data to the backend

```
 <script>

   
        function showTextBox(key){
            /*console.log(100);
            console.log(`textbox_${key}`);*/
            var textbox = document.getElementById(`textbox_${key}`);
            textbox.classList.toggle('hidden-textbox');
        }

        function saveValue(event,key){
            /*each task object has a primary key associated to it*/
            event.preventDefault();
            var primary_key=key;
            var enteredValue = document.getElementById(`inputValue_${primary_key}`).value;
           const base="{% url 'edit' 123 %}".slice(0, -4);
           const url=`${base}${primary_key}/`;
            fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
        body: JSON.stringify({ value: enteredValue }),
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
      
        }

      
   
    </script>
```

Below is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[

    path('addTask/',views.addTask, name="addTask"),
    path('mark_as_done/<int:pk>',views.mark_as_done, name="mark_as_done"),
    path('mark_as_undone/<int:pk>',views.mark_as_undone, name="mark_as_undone" ),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/',views.edit, name="edit"),
    path('delete_task/<int:pk>/',views.delete_task, name="delete_task")
]
```

below is the views.py

```
def edit(request,pk):
     
     enteredValue= request.POST.get('edited_task')
     get_task=get_object_or_404(Task,pk=pk)
     get_task.task=enteredValue
     get_task.save()
     return redirect('home')
```

and last but not least is the models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    is_completed= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

Everything bar the edit function is working as intended. Any ideas on what the issue could be?

I tried trouble shooting and debugging the code, and I think it may have to do with the url in my fetch, but I have tried so many different variations and nothing is working. I want the task to be changed to whatever you submit in the form.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your url is fine because the request is going through. Your issues seems to be coming from the `edit` function in your `views.py` specifically  the `get_task.save()` call. Check if `enteredValue` is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue `IntegrityError` will be raised if your `enteredValue`is of None type. Make sure you are sending in valid value.

### HANDLE JSON PAYLOAD

In addition to, modify your `edit` view. Since you are not using forms directly but via fetch api, you cannot use `request.POST.get` to get your `edited_task` data as this will only work if your content_type is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Now, you can change your content type in your javascript and also your payload encoding if you want.

But since you are opting to use `application/json` you have to extract the json payload from the `request.body` attribute instead like this:

```
import json # do this at the top
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST # move to top

@require_POST
def edit(request,pk):
    
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    enteredValue= data.get('edited_task')
    get_task=get_object_or_404(Task,pk=pk)
    
    if enteredValue is not None:
        get_task.task = enteredValue
        get_task.save()
        get_task.task=enteredValue
        get_task.save()
    return redirect('home')
```

This way you will only update the task if a non-NULL value is provided which will avoid the `not NULL CONSTRAINT` error.

Also, in your javascript call (`fetch api`), your payload does not have the correct key. Your view is expecting `edited_task`.

Change this portion of the code:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ value: enteredValue }),
```

To this:

```
body: JSON.stringify({ edited_task: enteredValue }),
```

Comment: I did the following changes above and made some progress, and did some more debugging , but when I add a print(enteredValue) to my views, I am getting None

Comment: @AbdulwasiiAjayi check my edited answer `view function`.